# Output all data from a SQL database in a styled manner

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am trying to output all data from a database in a styled manner. It doesn't seem to be complying, though. Here's the code:

The way I'm trying to output:

```
<?php

  include 'database.php';

 $sql = "SELECT * FROM patients";
 $result = $conn->query($sql);

 if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        echo "<div class='titleBox'>ID: " . $row["id"]. " : First Name : " . $row["fname"]. " : Last Name : " . $row["lastname"] . " : Age : " . $row["age"] . "</div><br>";
        echo "<div class='titleBox'>Description: " . $row["descript"] . "</div><br>";
    }
  } else {
    echo "<div class='titleBox'>No patients on record.</div>";
  }
  $conn->close();

?>
```

Connection to database:

```
<?php

        $server = "localhost";
        $username = "root2";
        $password = "passwordking";
        $db = "root2";



        try{
            $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db;", $username, $password);
        } catch(PDOException $e){
            die( "<div class='titleBox'>Connection failed: " . $e->getMessage() . "</div>");
        }
```

EDIT: Sorry 'bout that. There is nothing being outputted.

Comment: [RT*M](http://php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php)

Comment: I don't understand what your saying... Could you rephrase that? Thanks.

Comment: What isn't working? Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 1):

You need to tell us what error do you get or what is the problem with the script.

First of all, as Alton pointed out in the comments, you are mixing PDO and mysqli. You need to stick with one. Lets make it mysqli for the example.

your database.php

```
<?php

$server = "localhost";
$username = "root2";
$password = "passwordking";
$db = "root2";

$conn = new mysqli($server, $username, $password);

if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
}
```

Then save num_rows inside a variable and check if it's > 0

```
<?php

include 'database.php';

$sql = "SELECT * FROM patients";
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$rows_num = $result->num_rows; #store the number of rows

#use it in if statement
if ($rows_num > 0) {
   // output data of each row
   while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo "<div class='titleBox'>ID: " . $row["id"]. " : First Name : " . $row["fname"]. " : Last Name : " . $row["lastname"] . " : Age : " . $row["age"] . "</div><br>";
       echo "<div class='titleBox'>Description: " . $row["descript"] . "</div><br>";
   }
} else {
    echo "<div class='titleBox'>No patients on record.</div>";
}

$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: You should let them know that they are creating a PDO instance and using a mySQLi statement function on it (`$conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$server;dbname=$db;", $username, $password);`) - That's probably the first thing they should look into